# APDU MIFARE Classic 4K read value at specific sector/block

Tags: nfc, smartcard, mifare, apdu, smartcard-reader

I'm trying to read some data from my MiFare Classic 4K smartcard. I already know the exact sector/block location of the data (because of a dump via Android), but I don't know how to show it in SpringCard Prox'N'Roll.

I know how to access my card and I did a lot of research, but I'm not able to find out how to get data because I don't really understand the values needed in a APDU command message.

It might be something like this?

```
CLA: FF
INS: B0/B2/CA ?
P1-P2: ???
LC Field: ??
Data field: ??
```

http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_6_basic_interindustry_commands.aspx#chap6_1

I want to read sector 32, block 140.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most easiest way to read a block from a MIFARE Classic card using this specific reader (SpringCard Prox'N'Roll PC/SC) is the reader-specific READ MIFARE CLASSIC (with specified key) command:

```
FF F3 00 <BLOCK> 06 <KEY> 00
```

This command will try to authenticate using `<KEY>` as key A first (and if that fails as key B). After successful authentication it will read the block `<BLOCK>`.

So for your scenario, you would use

```
FF F3 00 8C 06 uu vv ww xx yy zz 00
```

where `uu vv ww xx yy zz` is the authentication key.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! It might be a stupid question but where can I find the authentication key?

Comment: The authentication key is a shared secret that was defined for that sector by whoever issued the card. So you should be able to get that key from them.

Comment: But I think it's accessible without authentication key because I can read the data in Springcard MemoryCardTool... So why would I need an authentication key when it's "public"?
Screenshot after clicking on the key-button: http://gyazo.com/4d768a889f0ba43a7f0043f71a0cf635

Comment: There is no concept of "public" with MIFARE Classic. You always need an authentication key. If the SpringCard tool can read the data it's likely that the data is readable using some standard key (e.g. transport key `FF FF FF FF FF FF`, NDEF key `D3 F7 D3 F7 D3 F7` or MAD key `A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5`).

Comment: As you mentioned Android earlier: if a tool like my [NFC TagInfo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo) is capable of reading the data, then you can see the keys it used to authenticate to that block as the first (key A)/last (key B) 6 bytes of the sector trailer block.